# Laravel 4 - routing - repeating segments in URL

Tags: php, laravel-4, url-routing

I have this URL:

```
example.org.ch/c123-Category-One
```

Where '123' is category ID which I need to pass to controller. Routing rule is:

```
Route::get('/c{id}-{slug}', [
  'as' => 'category.index',
  'uses' => 'Company\Package\CategoryController@view',
])->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

But I can have subcategories:

```
example.org.ch/c123-Category-One/c234-Category-Two
example.org.ch/c123-Category-One/c234-Category-Two/c567-Category-Three
..
example.org.ch/..X-LEVELS../c2846-Category-X
```

For these I tried this routing rule:

```
Route::get('{path}/c{id}-{slug}', [
  'as' => 'category.index',
  'uses' => 'Company\Package\CategoryController@view',
])->where(['path' => '.*', 'id' =>'[0-9]+']);
```

It works for 2nd level category and more but not for: `example.org.ch/c123-Category-One`

Is possible to have one rule for all cases?